# jquery .validate() failing after legit selector is insered

Tags: jquery, validation

something strange is happening to my code. When I change this

```
$("#event_form").validate();
$('input').not(':checkbox').addClass('required');
```

into this

```
$("#event_form").validate();
$('input').not(':checkbox, #advanced_view :input').addClass('required');
```

the code in the page keeps working fine (and "required" class gets added to the correct elements), but the validation plugin fails to apply the rules (so the page is sent without any javascript checks).

Any idea as to were could I look at?

Answer (score 0):

As adding the `required` class on elements only works on page load, you need to use the `rules` parameter on your input to add the validation, like this:

```
$('input').not(':checkbox, #advanced_view :input').rules("add", {
    required: true
});
```

[More info](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Comment: Not true. Anyway it doesn't work. The problem must be somewhere in the syntax (?)